# Construct a sum that evaluates its arguments but doesn't evaluate further

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I'm trying to construct a sum like this:

```
Sum[body, range]
```

where `body` is

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n!}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{(n+1)!}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{(n+2)!}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{(n+3)!}}$$

and range is $\{n,0,\infty \}$.

```
body = 1/Sqrt[n!] + 1/Sqrt[(1 + n)!] + 1/Sqrt[(2 + n)!] + 1/Sqrt[(3 + n)!]; 
range = {n, 0, Infinity};
```

This can be done by

```
Sum[Evaluate@body, Evaluate@range]
```

Out==>$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n!}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{(n+1)!}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{(n+2)!}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{(n+3)!}}\right)$$

But *Mathematica* takes a long time attempting to compute the sum, which I don't need it to do. Is there a way to prevent the computation of the sum but still evaluate the `body` and `range` parts?

I tried the Trott-Strzebonski in-place evaluation trick:

```
HoldForm[Sum[body, range]] /. Sequence[x__] :> RuleCondition[Evaluate[x]]
```

But it didn't work. Where did I do wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will just display but not calculate anything:

```
Defer[Sum[1/Sqrt[n!] + 1/Sqrt[(1 + n)!] + 1/Sqrt[(2 + n)!] + 
       1/Sqrt[(3 + n)!], {n, 0, Infinity}]]
```

Or,

```
Defer[Evaluate[Hold[Sum][body, range]]] /. Hold[Sum] -> Sum
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thanks, but the if you define body and range like in the question and do Defer[Sum[body,range]], it will not work. Since in my code the "body" and "range" are generated from other function, so I have to define a variable form them.

Comment: That's cool, thanks!

Comment: Actually, I sometimes wished "6.2 Nouns and Verbs" from [here](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/en/maxima_6.html) would make it into Mathematica one day ...

Answer (score 3):

```
body = 1/Sqrt[n!] + 1/Sqrt[(1 + n)!] + 1/Sqrt[(2 + n)!] + 
   1/Sqrt[(3 + n)!];
range = {n, 0, Infinity};
```

Perhaps, if you want something more or less general

```
HoldForm@Sum[body, range] /. 
 s_Symbol /; Context[s] != "System`" :> Block[{}, s /; True]
```

though the typical injection is

```
With[{body = body, range = range},
 HoldForm@Sum[body, range]
 ]
```

`Defer` would work too if you want an evaluatable output.